# Java amazon awssdk 2.16.1 - S3Client.headObject() on a folder throws NoSuchKeyException, even though folder exists

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

**The sample S3 content**:

[image]

**The java code:**

```
try {
    final S3Client s3Client = getS3Client(REGION_NAME, ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
    
    final HeadObjectResponse ho1 = s3Client
            .headObject(HeadObjectRequest.builder().bucket(BUCKET_NAME).key("serban/m/F1/").build());
    System.out.println(ho1.sdkHttpResponse().statusCode());
    
    final HeadObjectResponse ho2 = s3Client
            .headObject(HeadObjectRequest.builder().bucket(BUCKET_NAME).key("serban/m/F2red/").build());
    System.out.println(ho2.sdkHttpResponse().statusCode());
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

**The result that I can't explain:**

- `ho1.sdkHttpResponse().statusCode()` is 200, just as expected.
- second `headObject` call throws `software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.NoSuchKeyException: The specified key does not exist. (Service: S3, Status Code: 404, ... )`

**Other info:**

- `F1` is **empty**

  - it was created manually in the S3 console, using the `Create folder` button
- `F2red` contains a file

  - **however**, this folder was created by simply uploading that file to that location (`s3Client.putObject...`)
  - if I delete the file contained in `F2red`, **it disappears completely**.

**What am I missing ?**
**What's the difference between these 2 locations ?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

folders are an artificial construct for the limited human brain. Testing for the existence of folders is pointless. KEYS aka objects are what matter. S3 is not FileExplorer.